# facebook post wall how can I do?

Tags: facebook

I tried this code to post wall

```
<?php
   $app_id = "XXXXXXXX";
   $canvas_page = "XXXXXXXX";
   $message = "My story";
   $feed_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id="
                 . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" .urlencode($canvas_page) . "&message=" . $message;

   if (empty($_REQUEST["post_id"])) {
     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $feed_url . "'</script>");
  } else {
     echo ("Feed Post Id: " . $_REQUEST["post_id"]);
  }
?>
```

But I really want to post wall like this:

[image]

Someone can give me an example?please!

Comment: They are using a popup similar to Facebook popups in design.

Answer (score 0):

That image shows a pop-up that looks like a Facebook dialog, but is actually designed by the app developers so it would something you would build yourself.

P.S: I suggest trying to use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ instead of your current method.

Comment: I print images from MYSQL,and let images as result post to wall.
how to alter Feed Dialog example code?